# How to use align-regex to align text as column or matrix?

Tags: align

I am trying to align code using align-regex but I could not figure out how to solve the below problem.

This is what I have:

```
public class Person
{
    public static String id = "";
    private String name = "";
    public int age = 10;

}
```

This is what I am trying to get:

```
public class Person
{
    public  static String id =       "";
    private String name   =  "name";
    public  int    age    =  10;

}
```

**Actually I just want to separate them into each column.**

I have tried `M-x align-regex RET \(s-*\)\s-` and many more but none is working. Please help me solve this or advice me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind re-indenting afterwards:

<kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>M-x</kbd> `align-regex` <kbd>RET</kbd> `\(\s-+\)` <kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>

To re-activate the mark and re-indent should then be:

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd>

---

To avoid the need to re-indent, we need to enable it to ignore as much of the initial space as possible:

<kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>M-x</kbd> `align-regex` <kbd>RET</kbd> `\s-*\(\s-+\)` <kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>

Comment: it's work really nice but it adds one more TAB to the code everytime I try the command. Is that I done something wrong?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/8129994/324105 help?

Comment: And if you are indenting with *only* tabs and aligning with *only* spaces, then that gives you an easy way to ignore the indentation, by aligning on `\( +\)` (i.e. one-or-more spaces).